# Deinit ViewModel in the MVVM with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui

I am learning MVVM with the SwiftUI and I have problem with deinitialization of the ViewModel. The View is using ListView to show a data from ViewModel. If I go to the Detail Class of the ListView row and then go back to ListView the App creates duplicates of data.
For example: If a list has 100 items and I go to the DetailView of the list row and then go back, now is 200 items and so on. How to stop it?

ListView:

```
import SwiftUI
import KingfisherSwiftUI

struct ListView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel = ListViewModel()
@State private var searchText = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        VStack {
        SearchBar(text: $searchText)
            .padding(.top, -30)
        
        List(viewModel.itemsList) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: ListDetail()) {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    KFImage(URL(string: String(item.thumbnailUrl)))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0 ))
                    
                }
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .padding(.top, -10)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    
                    Text(item.albumTitle)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .padding(.bottom, 0)
                    
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
            }
        }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.fetchPhotos()
        }
    }
    }
}
```

ListViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {

private let persistenceService = PersistenceService()

@Published var albumsList = [Album]()
@Published var photosList = [Photo]()
@Published var usersList = [User]()
@Published var itemsList = [ListItem]()


func fetchAlbums() {
    albumsList += persistenceService.fetchAlbums()
}

func fetchPhotos() {
    photosList += persistenceService.fetchPhotos()
    
    fetchAlbums()
    if albumsList.count > 0 && photosList.count > 0 {
        setItemList()
    }
}

func setItemList() {
    
    if albumsList.count > 0 && photosList.count > 0 {
        let photo: Photo
        let album: Album
        
        itemsList = photosList.compactMap { photo in
            guard let album = albumsList.first(where: { $0.id == photo.id}) else {
                return nil
            }
            return ListItem(id: album.id, title: photo.title, albumTitle: album.title, thumbnailUrl: photo.thumbnailUrl)
        }
        
        print("Items  \(itemsList.count)")
    }
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid data duplication would be to move the fetching of the photos from the `onAppear` method to the `init`. So instead of

```
.onAppear {
    self.viewModel.fetchPhotos()
}
```

do it like this

```
init() {
    self.viewModel.fetchPhotos()
}
```